# Best collection in Java for user defined object to search using two comparators

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, collections, out-of-memory

I want a collection in Java which can be searched faster and with two comparators (one which compares Int member of object, other compares String member of object).

Is it possible with any collection ?

Secondly, I will be loading data from db2 to the collection of objects( containing 2 Int, 2 string and 2 object references) . Number of rows loaded from database can go upto 10000. So Will there be any problem related to memory or will JVM manage it?

Comment: with such volumes you shouldn't worry about memory.

Comment: Thanks @nikis ! any suggestion regarding my first doubt ?

Comment: What do you mean by searching with a comparator? Are you saying you want the data sorted? Are you saying you want the data to be unique with uniqueness defined by a comparator?

Comment: i mean that i could use collection.binarysearch with that collection. and could search and find an object that have a specific field matching to a search key

Comment: In such case you need two `ArrayList`s sorted with different comparator each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you can define two comparators.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyObject {
    private final int intProperty;
    private final String stringProperty;

    public MyObject(int intProperty, String stringProperty) {
        this.intProperty = intProperty;
        this.stringProperty = stringProperty;
    }

    public int getIntProperty() {
        return intProperty;
    }

    public String getStringProperty() {
        return stringProperty;
    }

    public static final Comparator<MyObject> intComparator = new Comparator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
             return o1.getIntProperty() == o2.getIntProperty() ? 0 : (o1.getIntProperty() < o2.getIntProperty() ? -1 : 1);
        }
    };

    public static final Comparator<MyObject> stringComparator = new Comparator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
            return o1.getStringProperty().compareTo(o2.getStringProperty());
        }
    };
};
```

Make a mutable list, which is the only input `Collections.sort` will accept:

```
List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new MyObject(1, "xyz"), new MyObject(2, "abc")));
```

Then:

```
Collections.sort(myObjects, MyObject.intComparator);  // (1, "xyz"), (2, "abc")
```

Or:

```
Collections.sort(myObjects, MyObject.stringComparator);  // (2, "abc"), (1, "xyz")
```

You can also use these comparators with other common data structures:

```
SortedSet<MyObject> objectSet = new TreeSet<>(MyObject.intComparator);
objectSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(new MyObject(1, "c"), new MyObject(2, "b"));
```

Comment: thanks ! but what could be the possible collections for myObjects  in above example?

Comment: @user3733814, see my updates above. `Collections.sort` can only sort `List`, probably because a `List` is the fundamental ordered `Collection`.

Comment: One last question... can a treeset or hashset be used effectively to find the object having intProperty ==search_Key ?. As as they don't allow duplicates and suites better for my application.

Comment: Yep, @user3733814. You can definitely use the `TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)` constructor to make a `SortedSet` that sorts by your desired keys. A plain `HashSet` of course won't give you sorting semantics. Check out my edit above.